# How refresh listview after search

Tags: android

i have a listview with data from database using an sqlite. 
when first time (onCreate()) i show the data, there`s no problems, the data all shown.

the problem is, when i want to filter my list view using datepicker and button, the listview not change the data.
i`ve use listview.invalidateViews(), notifyDataSetChanged()... but still not solved yet. maybe there`s some mistake with my code... hope you guys can give me some solution.
thx...

here`s my code

**Getting Data From DataBase**

```
    public ArrayList<BonRokokModel> getBonRokokList(String userGUID, String transDate, String searchText){
        dbPath =  "/data/data/app.chameleon.mobile/databases/";
        dbName = "SalesTrans.sqlite";
        bonRokok = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath + dbName, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String strQuery;
        strQuery = "SELECT BonRokokID, TransDate, Gudang, Status FROM tblSATBonRokok WHERE UserGUID = ? AND TransDate = ?";

//      if(!searchText.equals("")){
//          strQuery += "AND (BonRokokID LIKE %'"+ searchText +"'% ) ORDER BY TransDate DESC, BonRokokID Desc";
//      }   
        ArrayList<BonRokokModel> listRokok = new ArrayList<BonRokokModel>();
        Cursor mCursor = bonRokok.rawQuery(strQuery, new String[]{userGUID, transDate});

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                BonRokokModel dataRokok = new BonRokokModel();
                dataRokok.setBonRokokID(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("BonRokokID")));
                dataRokok.setTransDate(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("TransDate")));
                dataRokok.setGudang(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Gudang")));
                dataRokok.setStatus(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Status")));
                listRokok.add(dataRokok);
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        bonRokok.close();
        return listRokok;
    }
```

**My Code to Get Data**

```
public void settingTabItem() {
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bonRokokMain_lvMain);

        listviewMain = new ArrayList<BonRokokModel>();
        listviewMain = bonRokokDAO.getBonRokokList(Main_Login.userGUID,utilities.convertDateToDateDBString(edt1.getText().toString()),"");
        BonRokokListAdapter adapter = new BonRokokListAdapter(this, listviewMain);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

thank you

Comment: where you have filtered listView

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ..

```
ListArrayAdapter.clear(); // Clear your adapter
ListArrayAdapter.addAll(newItems); // Add new items to it
ListArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notify List view for new items in list
```

**OR**

You can update list view like this also ..

Firstly clear your list view ..

Then after fetching new data .... create complete list view again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the logical of method `settingTabItem()` on refresh method. Don't forget to clear the listview. Sorry for the bad English.